# When can i get sqlite3_open_v2 failure or why sqlite3_open_v2 fails

Tags: sqlite, embedded-linux

I was writing a program to create a database at the time of bootup of the serivce. 
The service is up and while trying to create database using sqlite3_open_v2 i am receiving an error and i am not able to create a database.
Code Snippet:

```
    int retVal;
    retVal = sqlite3_open_v2(filename.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL );
    if(retVal != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout<< "SQLite error: Database cannot be created."
        retVal = -1;
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you print out the error message. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html

Comment: Error received was error 14 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN)